# occur memory leak when import uuid

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, memory-leaks, uuid

I found memory leak when import uuid.

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gc
>>> gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> gc.garbage
[]
>>> import uuid
>>> gc.collect()
gc: collectable <tuple 026A2D30>
gc: collectable <_ctypes.PyCSimpleType 026DC190>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 026A4FA8>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 026A4FD0>
gc: collectable <tuple 026A5600>
gc: collectable <StgDict 026A61E0>
gc: collectable <tuple 026A84B0>
gc: collectable <StgDict 026AA7C8>
gc: collectable <_ctypes.PyCArrayType 026FAD30>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 026AD148>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 026AD170>
gc: collectable <tuple 026AC150>
gc: collectable <tuple 0269BA50>
gc: collectable <StgDict 026AA978>
gc: collectable <_ctypes.PyCFuncPtrType 026FB4D0>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 02699D50>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 02699E18>
gc: collectable <tuple 0269D180>
gc: collectable <tuple 0269BBF0>
gc: collectable <StgDict 026AAA50>
gc: collectable <_ctypes.PyCFuncPtrType 026FB6B8>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 026AD5D0>
gc: collectable <getset_descriptor 026AD5F8>
gc: collectable <tuple 0269D540>
25
**>>> gc.garbage**
[(<type '_ctypes._SimpleCData'>,), <class 'ctypes.c_longdouble'>, <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_longdouble' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_longdouble' objects>
ypes.c_longdouble'>, <type '_ctypes._SimpleCData'>, <type '_ctypes._CData'>, <type 'object'>), {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_longdouble' objects>, '_type_':
le__': 'ctypes', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_longdouble' objects>, '__doc__': None}, (<type '_ctypes.Array'>,), {'__module__': 'ctypes._endian', '__d
ibute '__dict__' of 'c_long_Array_3' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_long_Array_3' objects>, '_length_': 3, '_type_': <class 'ctypes.c_long'>,
ne}, <class 'ctypes._endian.c_long_Array_3'>, <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_long_Array_3' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_long_Array_3' objects>, (<class 'ctype
ong_Array_3'>, <type '_ctypes.Array'>, <type '_ctypes._CData'>, <type 'object'>), (<type '_ctypes.PyCFuncPtr'>,), {'__module__': 'ctypes', '__dict__': <attribute '__di
ncPtr' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of '_FuncPtr' objects>, '_flags_': 1, '__doc__': None, '_restype_': <class 'ctypes.c_long'>}, <class 'ctypes._
ttribute '__dict__' of '_FuncPtr' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of '_FuncPtr' objects>, (<class 'ctypes._FuncPtr'>, <type '_ctypes.PyCFuncPtr'>, <type '_ctypes._C
 'object'>), (<type '_ctypes.PyCFuncPtr'>,), {'__module__': 'ctypes', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of '_FuncPtr' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__'
' objects>, '_flags_': 1, '__doc__': None, '_restype_': <class 'ctypes.c_long'>}, <class 'ctypes._FuncPtr'>, <attribute '__dict__' of '_FuncPtr' objects>, <attribute '
of '_FuncPtr' objects>, (<class 'ctypes._FuncPtr'>, <type '_ctypes.PyCFuncPtr'>, <type '_ctypes._CData'>, <type 'object'>)]
**>>> len(gc.garbage)**
24
>>>
```

after search related resource, I found the same issue for import ctypes. I found that issue at http://bugs.python.org/issue12142.

I wonder whether this is also a bug I should report to bugs.python.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a leak. Setting `gc.DEBUG_LEAK` causes the garbage collector to append even collectable objects to the garbage list instead of freeing them. You can see that everything the collector found was freeable, since all the messages say `collectable`.

Comment: thanks for your response. But I have a new doubt, why does python documentation say gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL and gc.DEBUG_LEAK are useful for debugging a leaking program. in addition if it were set to DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE, it would be better to know whether the program has a leak.